# Android design time annotations (@Size, @IntRange etc.) equivalent in .NET

Tags: c#, android, .net

There is this feature in Android, where Android Studio warns me if I use some method not correctly on design time.

For example;

```cs
private void someMethod(@Size(max = 10) String input)
{
    // Some logic...
}
```

When I call this method, I cannot give a string parameter bigger than 10 chars. I don't have to handle this in runtime.

I was wondering if there is a similar way to do this in .NET? After a quick research, i found nothing.

[More information about Android code inspection annotations](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations)

Comment: Have you found a solution to your issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Solutions I've found could only solve this at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you refer to uses `com.android.support:support-annotations`, so my guess would be to install the [following NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations/) `Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations` and import the annotations in your files from this package.

I'm assuming here that you are using .NET for Android (Xamarin.Droid), if you do not then since these annotations are an Android feature you cannot use them in a
C# only project.

Both package are in version 28.0 so it seems up to date even if the last update was in 2019.